# A warning in R when using predict function in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to imputate missing values using preProcess. The code is simple. However, a warning occurred and it seems I cannot use knnImpute. I failed to find a correct explanation online.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Soybean)

library(caret)
imputationObj <- preProcess(Soybean, method = c('knnImpute'), na.remove = FALSE)
imputationObj
imputedSoybean <- predict(imputationObj, Soybean)
summary(imputedSoybean)

>     Warning in pre_process_options(method, column_types) :
>       The following pre-processing methods were eliminated: 'knnImpute', 'center', 'scale'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the data frame `Soybean` contains factors. From `?preProcess`, the first argument should be

> x 
>   a matrix or data frame. Non-numeric predictors are allowed but will be ignored.

but

```
R> class(Soybean[,2])
[1] "factor"
```

To put it another way, how would you centre a factor containing the value `red,`blue`and`green`.